# How to Read a Line of Text in a .txt File

Tags: python, discord

I am wanting to know how to make it to where instead of typing everything out for my random choosing message how to use a .txt file instead. Here is my code:

```
   import discord
   from discord.ext.commands import Bot
   from discord.ext import commands
   import asyncio
   import time
   import random
   import ctx
   import timeit
   import traceback
   import logging

   bot_prefix = "!"
   bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)


   @bot.event
   async def on_ready():
   print("Bot Online!")
   print("Name: {}".format(bot.user.name))
   print("ID: {}".format(bot.user.id))

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def getalt(ctx):
    msg = ["danielmarmeloreis@gmail.com:slime1234", "danielkrock9@yahoo.com:sagaraghi123", "danielemilerevah@gmail.com:truffles101", "danieldiazlauraagudo@hotmail.com:manolo39", "e1verity@yahoo.com:Blessed1", "daniellachner64@gmail.com:london2004", "dyllonng@gmail.com:t0403752e", "danielgrolik@web.de:26101999", "danielspaniel6011@gmail.com:coolboy12", "dyllindsay@live.com:Spiderman23", "eac141099@hotmail.com:Megustaelpan", "eafut13playgood@hotmail.de:sinanovic1", "dyllynnbell@gmail.com:mdb74523", "danielvtotino@rogers.com:dvt2002", "danilklin17@gmail.com:Vfvjxrf1979", "danieltavazzi@alice.it:tavazzi96", "danilofleischer@web.de:FcBayern69", "danielgibert@hotmail.com:costurera01", "danielkozak51@gmail.com:Jetsfan7", "eagle3_2003@yahoo.com:brophy", "eab202303986@eabdf.br:GDF2005", "danijano1999@hotmail.cl:dact1999", "eaglenebulangc6611@gmail.com:Robotics", "danielsimovski23@gmail.com:kikoman23", "dyllanweich@outlook.com:djdyllan1", "danielarendt282@gmail.com:Lego1234", "danielbrodie04@gmail.com:nirvanna2", "daniele.vavala@gmail.com:milo123456", "e.duckworth11@gmail.com:AgentP00", "danielfelipe142009@hotmail.com:samuel1254", "danielkautz139@googlemail.com:Jagd123", "e_wetzl@yahoo.de:yolo1234", "danielograbek@gmail.com:danielo2000", "e3zofficiel@gmail.com:nintendo64", "e.dundon95@gmail.com:Eoinqzell95", "e.boy612@gmail.com:angels612", "e99wright@gmail.com:Monkey99", "dynodriver52@gmail.com:school09", "e319707@gmail.com:ilovetacos11"]
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, random.choice(msg))
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Alt Has Been Seen To Your DMs")
```

Where I have the email and passwords I would like to use a .txt file for it instead of me having to type in every one. And as you can see there is only 1 email and pass combo per command usage, so in my txt file I would have every combo on a new line.

Comment: Store credentials in a JSON file?

Comment: please correct the indentation problem in your code and put each string of  `msg` in a newline so people wouldn't have to scroll to see all of it.

Comment: @ROAR I don’t think you realize how many lines that would be... I thank you for your reply but that revision is un needed

Comment: then you can just not put _all_ the strings here. just put a few as an example.

Comment: @ROAR there I shortened it some

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask].  Seems like you have defined your requirements well - work your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and you will get a general feel for the tools that Python offers to help you solve your problem(s).

Answer (score 0):

[file read and write](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

I'm having a little trouble understanding your problem but if you're just wanting to read in the lines from your email file then store them in a list:

```
    emailFile = open("emailFile.txt", "r")
    emails = []
    for email in emailFile:
        emails.append(email)
```

This expects that your emailFile.txt has a singular email per line

Comment: You can use a similar mechanic/ logic structure to write to this or a different file

Comment: I’m sorry I’m not being very clear here I am new to this... I am trying to get the bot to send them a random message from a list of email:password in a text file that is on my desktop

Comment: So I would like to use a text file with the list of information rather than the lengthy msg variable I have there

Comment: Edited answer slightly

Comment: Much simpler: `emails = list(emailFile)`.